# How can I verify a user's role when they log in using identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Good morning to all the members, greeting to all.

How can I verify a user's role when they log in using Identity?
First step register 
Second step, login, but when I try to access a view with "Admin" permissions, it says "Access denied. You do not have access to this resource."
I want every user that registers to have the role of administrator.

What am I doing wrong?

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public IActionResult About()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

    return View();
}
//DBContext
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace test.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "Admin".ToUpper() });
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole { Name = "User", NormalizedName = "User".ToUpper() });
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
        public DbSet<Test> Test { get; set; }
    }
}




//Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //DataBase Connection
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    // Library Identity
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    // IdentityOptions
    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        // Default SignIn settings.
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
        // Password settings.
        options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;

        // Lockout settings.
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

        // User settings.
        options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false; // ojo con esto
    });
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseAuthentication(); //  Use Authentication
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
// Register.cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var UserRole = "Admin"; // Admin Role
            var x = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, UserRole); // Assignment of the role to the registered user
            _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
        }
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
        }
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

Comment: [Filter attributes, including AuthorizeAttribute, can only be applied to PageModel and cannot be applied to specific page handler methods.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2#adding-role-checks). Scroll down to the end of the section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known bug in the version of 2.1 . See [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813) here .

I follow the advice of [using the old api suggested by HaoK and C-BERBER](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813#issuecomment-413928717) , and it now works flawlessly .

Configure the identity using the old-style api :

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
       .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
       .AddDefaultUI()
       .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```